# SQL Search Query with Selective Conditions

Tags: sql

I am trying to fetch results from a DB for several records.

`Table 1                                    Table 2`
`UserID UserName    DOB     RegistrationID  CourseID    UserID
u1      UA       1/1/1900       1             C1         u1
u2      UB       1/2/1900       2             C2         u3
u3      UC       1/3/1900       3             C4         u2
u4      UD       1/4/1900       4             C3         u3`

My search criteria would be

- U1-Q3
- U2-Q1
- U3-Q2

The results for each user should only fetch its related course value..

```
`Where t1.userid = u1 and t2.courseid = q3.. `
```

I need to fetch this for over 100 record combinations
like

`where t1.userid = u1 and t2.courseid = c1
and t1.userid = u2 and t2.courseid = c4
and t1.userid = u1 and t2.courseid = c3`
etc....

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Your JOIN needs an ON clause.

Comment: Insert your conditions into a temporary table and then join to them

Comment: @PankajSolanki Are you really want to join User u1 and Course C3, although the Course C3 has the foreign key u3?

Comment: You need `OR` between the different combinations. E.g. `... or (t1.userid = u2 and t2.courseid = c4) or ...`.

Comment: How do you find all those combinations?

Comment: Sample Data base:
http://www.dofactory.com/sql/sandbox

Here is where i need to filter the data

Comment: So far i have joined the Tables:

select [o].id as [OrderID], [O].CustomerID as [CustomerID], 
[Oi].Orderid as [OIOrderID], OI.ProductID, P.ProductName, P.ID AS [ProductIDa], P.IsDiscontinued,
s.city, s.country
from [order] o 
inner join [orderitem] oi on o.id = oi.orderid
inner join [product] p on oi.productid = p.id  
inner join [supplier] s on p.supplierid = s.id

Answer (score 0):

I asume you are looking for a join query like this, otherwise please provide more information:

```
SELECT UserDetails 
FROM Users t1
LEFT JOIN Courses t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId
```

For this query to run successfully you need a foreign key UserId in the Courses table.

Moreover you could have a foreign key CourseId in the 'User' table and use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users t1
LEFT JOIN Courses t2 ON t2.CourseId = t1.CourseId
```

A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

[Quick explanation of Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

[Here you can find and test on an example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join)

If you have question on how to create foreign keys look at this section:

[Foreign Keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: I have managed to join the tables like the below.. however need the condition/join type to filter for only one country orders


select [o].id as [OrderID], [O].CustomerID as [CustomerID], 
[Oi].Orderid as [OIOrderID], OI.ProductID, P.ProductName, P.ID AS [ProductIDa], P.IsDiscontinued,
s.city, s.country
from [order] o 
inner join [orderitem] oi on o.id = oi.orderid
inner join [product] p on oi.productid = p.id  
inner join [supplier] s on p.supplierid = s.id